# request and response in iPhone to php decreases speed

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, json, ipad

I'm using php files to get data from mysql to iPhone app, to illustrate my mean I used this code in php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user_name = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$db_name = "db_name";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user_name,$password)or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("set names utf8");

$SQL= "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE 1";

$RS = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($RS))
$output[]=$row;

    $json_encode =json_encode($output);
    $utf8_decode = utf8_decode($json_encode);
    echo $json_encode;
    mb_convert_encoding($json_encode, 'UTF-8');
    $html_entity_decode = html_entity_decode($json_encode);
```

?>

and in iPhone I used this code:

```
NSString *phpUrl = @"url of my php file";

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpUrl]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{
    NSString *sEmailID = [status objectForKey:@"ID"];
    NSString *sEmail = [status objectForKey:@"Email"];
    NSString *sPassword = [status objectForKey:@"Password"];
    NSString *sSMTP = [status objectForKey:@"SMTP"];
}
```

and this works ok for me and I got my data. I also uses this way many times in my app.
But my problem is that the request and response leads to decrease the speed of my app and made it works so slowly. Is there are any ways to decrease the speed of request and response or is there are any alternative ways instead of this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: ok I'll keep this in consideration. Thanks

Comment: Are you creating/destroying the connection to the server for every request? Because that would likely cause you a lot of overhead and slow things down.

Comment: I'm new in Php I used many php file for every table in mysql and many function to get from each table so I think that I send request many times for each table but not destroy the connection as I'm not using mysql_close().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a synchronous request, and this will block your thread until the request completes. In general, this is not recommended, also because you cannot properly handle errors. You should perform asynchronous requests instead. Something like this:

```
NSString *phpUrl = @"url of my php file";

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpUrl]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
    {
        NSString *sEmailID = [status objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString *sEmail = [status objectForKey:@"Email"];
        NSString *sPassword = [status objectForKey:@"Password"];
        NSString *sSMTP = [status objectForKey:@"SMTP"];
    }
}];
```

[RTM](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works with me but this makes the data comes too late and it implements the functions and the data didn't come meaning that it dosen't wait for data to come and implements the code anyway either if the data came or not and this leads my data to not save in my local sqlite3 database. :S

Comment: That is an asynchronous call. That means the method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` returns immediately and does not block until the request completes. Because of that, you'd usually have to show some sort of loading screen. In the completionHandler block you have to do everything that must be done after the request completes, not outside of it.

Comment: consider that I want to add my data to array and get it out of this code for example :  `About *tempAbout = [[About alloc] initWithUniqueId:sAboutID2 Phone1:sPhone1 Phone2:sPhone2 Jawal:sJawal Fax:sFax WebSite:sWebSite Email:sEmail Address:sAddress ];
            
            [aboutMutableArray addObject:tempAbout];` then I want to use this aboutMutableArray in any place on code, how can I do this?

Comment: @user1553381 Just do that inside the completionHandler block and then reload whatever views you need.

Comment: how to send post in this type of request?

Comment: @user1553381 If you want to go beyond this, I suggest you use AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking and look into its AFHTTPClient which makes it easy to send any type of request including data (such as images) in multipart forms.